# How to use jQuery on Click with Typescript methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm having some issues calling a private method in my class with jquery's on click functionality. When I load my web app I get the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.changeView is not a function
```

This is what I have for my class.

```
module web {

    export class Menu {

        constructor(evt) {
            // text
        }

        private init() : void {

            this.menu = $(".application-menu a");
            this.menu.on("click", (evt) => this.changeView(evt) );
        }

        private changeView(evt : any) : void {
            console.log("do something");
        }

    }

}
```

How can I call jquery's on click functionality using typescript method as the callback?

Comment: Who's calling `init`? Seems like it was invoked without a correct `this` context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me... although I have made some adjustments and additions to test it, the fundamental principle is unchanged.

I'm not sure where you intended to call the `init` method... either you were calling it elsewhere (in which case it can't be private) or you intended to call it from within the class, but you didn't show that in your question. I have made it public for the purposes of the demonstration.

```
module web {

    export class Menu {
        private menu: JQuery;

        constructor() {
            // text
        }

        init() : void {

            this.menu = $(".application-menu a");
            this.menu.on("click", (evt) => this.changeView(evt) );
        }

        private changeView(evt : any) : void {
            console.log("do something");
        }
    }
}

var menu = new web.Menu();
menu.init();
```

This compiles to the following JavaScript...

```
var web;
(function (web) {
    var Menu = (function () {
        function Menu() {
            // text
        }
        Menu.prototype.init = function () {
            var _this = this;
            this.menu = $(".application-menu a");
            this.menu.on("click", function (evt) { return _this.changeView(evt); });
        };
        Menu.prototype.changeView = function (evt) {
            console.log("do something");
        };
        return Menu;
    })();
    web.Menu = Menu;
})(web || (web = {}));
var menu = new web.Menu();
menu.init();
```

When executed, this results in "do something" being [output to the console](http://jsfiddle.net/d8squv7a/).

Comment: I need to clarify a bit more, because your answer does work. I have two classes App and Menu. I'm using EventEmitter to communicate between the classes.

So I instantiated an app, then within it instantiated the Menu and emitted an event so that the Menu itself can start working. I think the problem I'm running into is that since the event is made from App and I'm just passing the object into Menu, it still thinks its in App and it's not finding the function I need.

Comment: @gladiator_flow can you post a short working example online somewhere so I can download it and see it all in action?